# A simple socket server and client program using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, client-server

SocketServer Program
This code is in raspberry:

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
"""
The request handler class for our server.

It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
override the handle() method to implement communication to the
client.
"""

def handle(self):
    # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
    print self.data
    # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
    self.request.sendall(self.data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

# Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

# Activate the server; this will keep running until you
# interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
server.serve_forever()
```

Socket Client Program
This code is in my laptop:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "192.168.1.40", 3360
data='Hello'
#data = data.join(sys.argv[1:])
# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data + "\n")

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = sock.recv(1024)
finally:
    sock.close()
print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

Here the data sent should be received to server and sent back to client.

This is the error:

> [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to `HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 9999` in the server. Now the server should listen on **all** interfaces and not just the loopback interface. The same could also be achieved using an empty string i.e `HOST, PORT = "", 9999`.